# c# form inheritance event handlers fire twice

Tags: c#, inheritance, button

I inherit from a root form that has a next and back button in, then use these buttons on some subforms and get the buttons called twice, i beleive the problem to be outlined in the MSDN here:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e33683a5(VS.71).aspx

how would i apply the advice they give to C# rather than VB?

It is causing lots of problems having all my buttons called twice, thanks.

Code:

**Root Form**

```
public partial class rootForm : Form
    {
        public rootForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void rootForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //used for all generic strings e.g. buttons
            this.Text = Resources.UIStrings.FormTitle.ToString();
            this.btnNext.Text = Resources.UIStrings.btnNext.ToString();
            this.btnBack.Text = Resources.UIStrings.btnBack.ToString();
        }
```

From designer:

```
        // btnNext
        // 
        this.btnNext.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.btnNext, "btnNext");
        this.btnNext.Name = "btnNext";
        this.btnNext.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

**Install Form**

from designer

```
        // 
        // btnNext
        // 
        this.btnNext.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(373, 360);
        this.btnNext.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 23);
        this.btnNext.TabIndex = 7;
        this.btnNext.Text = "Install";
        this.btnNext.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.installButton_Click);
```

From Form:

```
    private void installButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     doSomeStuff();
    }
```

Call Stack from VS for BOTH times the event is called

```
Installer.exe!Installer.InstallerForm.installButton_Click(object sender = {Text = "Siguiente"}, System.EventArgs e = {X = 21 Y = 10 Button = Left}) Line 226    C#

    [External Code] 

Installer.exe!Installer.Program.Main() Line 21 + 0x1d bytes C#

[External Code]
```

**Edit2**
tracing the callstack back with a breakpoint gives:

```
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.InstallerForm.installButton_Click
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.Program.Main
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
 ******************* Function: myInstaller.InstallerForm.installButton_Click(object, System.EventArgs), Thread: 0xE00 Main Thread

myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.InstallerForm.installButton_Click
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.Program.Main
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
 ******************* Function: myInstaller.InstallerForm.installButton_Click(object, System.EventArgs), Thread: 0xE00 Main Thread
```

**If i attach to the designer section where the handler is added i get**

```
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.InstallerForm.InitializeComponent
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.InstallerForm.InstallerForm
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.WelcomeForm.btnNext_Click
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.Program.Main
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
 ******************* Function: myInstaller.InstallerForm.InitializeComponent(), Thread: 0xA34 Main Thread

myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.InstallerForm.InitializeComponent
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.InstallerForm.performChecks
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.InstallerForm.InstallerForm
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.WelcomeForm.btnNext_Click
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run
myInstaller.exe!myInstaller.Program.Main
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart
 ******************* Function: myInstaller.InstallerForm.InitializeComponent(), Thread: 0xA34 Main Thread
```

But this shouldn't be as it looks like the form is getting created twice? but if i put a breakpoint on the installerform creator it is only called once.

Comment: could you add some code of how do you inherit and use buttons?

Comment: called twice to the same method? or called twice, once to the base handler and once to the inherited forms handler.

Comment: Your going to have to provide a code snippet...

Comment: what action is executed twice - `installButton_Click`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

could you add some code of how do you inherit and use buttons? 
In C# you should not have a such issue, because there is no `Handles` keyword.

You may, however, add multiple time handlers to the buttons event click like:

```
parent
    myButton.Click += myClickAction

child
    sameButton.Click += sameClickAction
```

When inheriting you should not click on the inherited buttons in designer(that will add a new, maybe the same, action on the inherited button)

Add a breackpoint in the twice executed action, when hit consult the CallStack Visual Studio Window in order to see who calls your method twice...

**EDIT**

Not sure what happens, but try the following:

Replace:

```
this.btnNext.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.installButton_Click);
```

with

```
this.btnNext.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.installButton_Click);
this.btnNext.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.installButton_Click);
this.btnNext.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.installButton_Click);
this.btnNext.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.installButton_Click);
```

**EDIT2**

In order to analyze the calls to your method instantly do the following:

1. Set a Tracepoint in the installButton_Click method:
   [alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S13KtR6tpYI/AAAAAAAAC9s/GpCZpXEukv4/s800/3setBreackpoint.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S13KtR6tpYI/AAAAAAAAC9s/GpCZpXEukv4/s800/3setBreackpoint.png)
2. Edit the tracepoint properties, in order to trace the callstack(or also use just **$CALLER** - only theprevious function): 
   [alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S13KtE98okI/AAAAAAAAC9o/gW5TfXouQDM/s800/2brackpoint.png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S13KtE98okI/AAAAAAAAC9o/gW5TfXouQDM/s800/2brackpoint.png)
3. In the Output window deactivate(right click) all messages but "Program Output";
4. Analyze your output in run-time:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S13Ks9YHEHI/AAAAAAAAC9k/WgnO5cBtUxI/s800/1output.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S13Ks9YHEHI/AAAAAAAAC9k/WgnO5cBtUxI/s800/1output.png)

Comment: added some code, I can't see a repeated handler and a search turned up nothing.

Comment: Ok the call stack shows this: 

    MynetInstaller.exe!MynetInstaller.InstallerForm.installButton_Click(object sender = {Text = "Siguiente"}, System.EventArgs e = {X = 60 Y = 9 Button = Left}) Line 226 C#

both times, so both times its called by the button with text "Siguiente" (next)?

Comment: i'm not exactly sure how to see, i've not used this part of VS much, how would I do that? thanks

Comment: i get that line above, then
[external code]
Installer.exe!Installer.Program.Main() Line 21 + 0x1d bytes
[external code]

And get identical entries both times it is called

Comment: Thanks Serhio, It stops when I add that change, but will only run the button once even if you generate a new click event. but a passable work around, does this point to an underlying reason for thie behaviour?

Comment: Apparently somewhere in the code you subscribe twice to your event. The multiple `-=` unsubscribe multiple instances, and adds only one, but, normally, you should add a tracepoint(breackpoint with a 'when hit..' condition) and correct the code do not add twice the same handler to this Click event.

Comment: hmmm would a search have no turned up the second subscription? leaving it 'as is' is a bit annoying as whenever you open the form it raises a warning that the underlying code has been changed and that this could cause problems! How would a breakpoint help? thanks for all your help

Comment: thats again for your help, i've done as you recommended but they both seem identical?

Comment: ok, they are really identical, could you now move the same tracepoint at the `this.btnNext.Click +=` line and paste the trace?

Comment: as you ca see, the difference is in the `InstallerForm.performChecks` function(called in InitializeComponent?). So, perhaps it adds the second time the handler.

Its better anyway to move all initialization custom logic (as `performChecks`) from `InitializeComponent` to `OnLoad` or `_Load` in the form.

Comment: Perfect, i removed those sections and its solved, the code only runs once! Thank you for your help serhio, i owe you one!

Answer (score 0):

C# adds event handlers to controls this way.

this.btnMyButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnMyButton_Click);

Just take a look if you have something like the statement above for your button within the derived form, if so, remove/comment it, since it is adding an additional event handler for that button.

Comment: I have looked and can't see one, i have also done a search for this.btnMyButton_Click in my project and found a single reference.

Comment: search `btnNext.Click` and `btnMyButton_Click` (without `this.`)

Comment: the only reference is in designer as i've shown above,  (one in each of the three different subforms inherited from "rootForm" )

Answer (score 0):

If you don't resolve it yet try remove creation (+=) of the event in the inherited form and let the event method only (button_click). In example below I've created a button which is using in the inherited form and its behaviour is different there but no fire event from base:

```
FormA : Form 
{
   ...
   protected System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonBase = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
   this.buttonBase.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonBase_Click);

   protected virtual void buttonBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Hi from base", "Hello");
   }
}

FormB : FormA
{
   ...
   // comment or remove line below, othervise you'll see "Hi from inherited form" twice
   // this.buttonBase.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonBase_Click);         

   protected override void buttonBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Hi from inherited form", "Elo");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you created form B as inherited from a base form A then all events defined in form A are automatically active in your inherited form B.

If in your form B you add an event then both base A form's event and your new B form's event will be called - first base form's event then your B form's event.

if you want to "override" that is disable base A form's event you should:
1) change A form's event's declaration from private to protected (so that your B form can see it)
2) open B's form constructor and subtract that event with -=

Answer (score 0):

During adding data to database table when I click on the add button then automatically firing twice time and using this code the problem was solved.

```
public void addEmployee(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

    controlsAdd.addBtn.Click -= new EventHandler(controlsAdd.addEmpInfToTable);
    controlsAdd.upDateBtn.Click -= new EventHandler(controlsAdd.updateEmployee); 
    controlsAdd.deleteBtn.Click -= new EventHandler(controlsAdd.deleEmployee);

     splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
     controlsAdd.AddControls(splitContainer1);


                }
```

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-to-or-remove-from-a-collection-of-controls-at-run-time